# A difference of Python from R

Tags: r, python-3.x

Coming from R, the following Python code does confuse me:

```py
In [22]: a = [1, 2, 3]
In [23]: b=a
In [24]: b
Out[24]: [1, 2, 3]
In [25]: b[0]=100
In [26]: b
Out[26]: [100, 2, 3]
In [27]: a
Out[27]: [100, 2, 3]
```

Why does `a` also change although I only change `b`?

Comment: You need to create a copy of 'a'  `b = copy.deepcopy(a)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list by value not by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469511/python-vs-r-scope/52469728

Answer (score 3):

When you do:

```
b=a
```

You are assigning `b` to the same object as `a`, *i.e.* `b` points to the same object in memory as `a`

This can be verified with:

```
>>> b is a
True
```